# PHP string-formatting: Capitalize first three letters, add hyphen and capitalize first letter of next word for strpos() matches

Tags: php, string, parsing, string-formatting, php-7

I'm attempting to consistently format a list of strings that were inconsistently uploaded into the database and will likely continue to be poorly formatted. I have a check for strings that begin with "us" or "usw":

```
if (strpos($string, 'us') !== false ||
    strpos($string, 'usw' !== false)
    ) {
    // Format string so that the us/usw are uppercase and there is a hyphen after. 
    // Sample strings: ussetup, uswadmin, Uswonsite, etc.
    // Ideal return for above: US-Setup, USW-Admin, USW-Onsite...
}
```

Some are Us/Usw or us/usw, but all just need to be uppercase, followed by a hyphen and the first letter of the next word capitalized. I'm not very familiar with parsing and formatting strings in PHP, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use `strtolower()` on everything, then `ucwords()` after, I tend to think would work, if that's what the question is about. Edit: Ok.. maybe not, because of the hyphens.

Comment: For sure not. Example, Ussales would go from that to ussales and back to Ussales.

Comment: `Ussales` so the plot thickens then. You're going to have to include that in your question. Are you wanting to get back `UsSales`?

Comment: Did you see the Sample strings and Ideal return comments? Ussales needs to return as US-Sales. Ussetup to US-Setup and so on. I also am formatting strings that begin with usw and suffer the same issues; uswsales to USW-Sales, uswsetup to USW-Setup.

Comment: But there is some ambiguity with "usw": uswadmin should become USW-Admin, but what about usweather? Not USW-Eather..., right?

Comment: True. There aren't any cases where this would be an issue, but it certainly could come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe go for `preg_replace_callback`, like this:

```
$string = "uswsetup"; // example input string
$result = preg_replace_callback("/^(usw?)-?(.)/mi", function ($m) {
    return strtoupper("$m[1]-$m[2]");
}, $string); 

echo $result; // USW-Setup
```

Comment: Just for info: this answer and the one below will work with 1-byte charsets only (for ASCII it's only English and Spanish languages). I suggest use `mb_strtoupper` and other functions from the `mbstring` library.

Answer (score 3):

```
function formatString($s)
{
    $s_low = strtolower($s) ; // full string in lower case

    if( substr($s_low, 0, 3) == 'usw' )
        return 'USW-' . ucfirst(substr($s_low, 3)) ;
    elseif( substr($s_low, 0, 2) == 'us' )
        return 'US-' . ucfirst(substr($s_low, 2));
}
```

This function will return the second part in lowercase, except for the first letter. If you want to keep it intact, just replace `$s_low` per `$s` in the substring parts.